# Send phone call command from PC to landline phone without Internet

Tags: pc, telephony, voip

I have a client who has NO INTERNET, and wants to connect his landline business phone to the computer, just to dial numbers direct from computer.

For example: He has in the computer a list of phone numbers he needs to dial, and wants to click on a number, and send a dial command to the phone to dial this number from the phone. Is that possible? Is there any hardware that enables the computer to connect to the phone and send commands?

Answer (score 0):

Small PABX with CTI interface. New one might cost ~$200 (talking about local market 2/6 extensions PABX, this would depend on country), used one would be cheaper.

If he would be fine with voice over PC headset, not through desk phone then Fax/Voice modem would be dirt cheap. It might be important to look for one with bundled software though. Maybe there is something with voice passthrough option.

Comment: For example [this PABX](https://www.amazon.com/Excelltel-SOHO-PBX-Telephone-Control-Exchange/dp/B015MIQ12A) is what you mean?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to PABX product with CTI ? so I can better understand that

Comment: https://www.platan.eu/offer/ip-pbx-telephone-systems/prima-mini.html with https://www.platan.pl/oferta/oprogramowanie/platan-cti.html but it might be hard to find distributor outside of Poland. Probably other vendors should have something similar. I'm not sure if CTI software is free at the moment, some time ago there was free version for 2 extensions so maybe someone stll can find and use it, alternatively custom software can be written in a few days.

Comment: I don't see any interface (serial port, ethernet) on Excelltel PABX, so it is highly unlikely that it can work with PC. It looks like some kind of non-configurable PABX with fixed numbers and call scheme.